# Invoking methods using expression language

Tags: java, spring, el

In my spring's config I need invoke method "get" (java.lang.ThreadLocal's instance object). How I can do it without creating new class with "correct" method's naming (smt like "getValue" instead of "get")?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. EL is following the JavaBeans convention. You have two options:

- define a custom JSTL function that retrieves the objects
- create a wrapper class the has, say, `getThreadLocalValue()` and access it via `bean.threadLocalValue`